# File.delete() fails to delete files in a directory

Tags: java, io

After writing the text files into a directory, i am trying to delete the empty files written by the PrintWriter.

File.delete() function fails to delete the file. Below is the code for writing and deleting.

```
private static void writeFile(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listRowVal, String szOutputDir, ArrayList<String> listHeader){     
       PrintWriter pw  = null;         
       try {                    
           ArrayList<String> listCells = listRowVal.get(0);            
           int iCells = listCells.size();          
           for(int k=0; k<iCells; k++){
               String language = listHeader.get(k);
               String szFileName = "files_"+ language +".csv";                 
               pw  = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(szOutputDir + File.separator + szFileName));               
               for(ArrayList<String> listNCRCellVal : listRowVal){
                   String szVal = listNCRCellVal.get(k);
                   if(szVal != null && szVal.trim().length() > 0){
                       pw.println(szVal);
                   }
                   pw.flush();                
               }                   
           }           

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {
            if(pw != null){
             pw.close();
             pw = null;
            }
            //System.gc();
            deleteEmptyFiles(szOutputDir);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

   }
 private static void deleteEmptyFiles(String szDirPath) {
        File file = new File(szDirPath);
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            String[] files = file.list();
            if (files.length > 0) {
                for (String szFileName : files) {
                    File deleteFile = new File(szDirPath + File.separator + szFileName);
                    if (deleteFile.length() == 0) {                     
                        //deleteFile.setWritable(true, false);
                        boolean bdeleted = deleteFile.delete();                     
                        if(bdeleted){
                            System.out.println(deleteFile.getName() + " deleted.");                         
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What is going wrong..??

Comment: do you get any exception? If yes, please give a stacktrace.

Comment: Do you get any exception? have you tried to debug?

Comment: offtopic - consider using Java 7  (try with  resources). Your code will be more readable.

Comment: What seems to be going wrong? What do you expect to see in your output, and what's actually happening?

Comment: The file could not exist, you may not have permissions to the file, or another process may have a lock on the file.  Without your stack trace, we can't be certain.

Comment: @Akash,@Andrew Janke,@Tim Biegeleisen..sorry for late response..It is not giving any exception..and file is generated in the directory..

Comment: Then how do you know that the `File.delete()` method is not working? It may also happen that `deleteEmptyFiles` method is not being called. Are you sure about it?

Comment: @Blip, deleteEmptyFiles is calling..now this issue is resolved..check below post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must close **each** PrintWriter, i.e. pw.close() must be on the end of "k" loop.

Comment: Further to this, the close() should be in a finally { ... } block.

Comment: Thanks..it's deleting now.